# DocBook DSSSL test failure

Tags: compiling, lfs

So I followed [these (Linux From Scratch) instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/docbook-dsssl.html) to test my build of DocBook DSSSL, and I get this:

```
$ onsgmls -sv test.sgm
onsgmls:I: "OpenSP" version "1.5.2"
onsgmls:test.sgm:1:61:W: cannot generate system identifier for public text "-//Davenport//DTD DocBook V3.0//EN"
onsgmls:test.sgm:1:61:E: reference to entity "CHAPTER" for which no system identifier could be generated
onsgmls:test.sgm:1:0: entity was defined here
onsgmls:test.sgm:1:61:E: DTD did not contain element declaration for document type name
onsgmls:test.sgm:2:8:E: element "CHAPTER" undefined
onsgmls:test.sgm:2:15:E: element "TITLE" undefined
onsgmls:test.sgm:3:5:E: element "PARA" undefined
```

I have tried to retrace my steps by uninstalling and reinstalling the dependencies... without success.

Comment: Is this still a relevant question or are you past this?

Comment: Am not yet past it. It's a major roadblock to building GNOME on LFS for me.

Comment: Have you checked the bug tracker for DocBook and OpenSP for anything related?

Comment: I have checked Google, LFS mailing lists and LFS IRC channel. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

The LFS page instructs to install DocBook SGML DTD 3.1 and 4.5, but the document you are building evidently uses DocBook SGML DTD 3.0.  So you need to get that version (or adjust the test document).  The instructions you are following are faulty in that regard.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your distribution already has packages for docbook.  Looking at Debian/Ubuntu I see packages for docbook, docbook-dsssl, and several others.  FreeBSD has Docbook in ports and I'm sure many other Linux distribution have it as well.  This will be must easier than installing Docbook from source.

Comment: You might have missed the part that this is LFS.