# I am failing to build DocBook-utils

Tags: compiling

I was following [these instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/docbook-utils.html) (DocBook-utils 0.6.14), and now I get the following failure when running `make`:

```
...
SGML_CATALOG_FILES=/etc/sgml/catalog \
SGML_SEARCH_PATH=../../doc:.. \
    nsgmls ../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml | \
    sgmlspl ../../helpers/docbook2man-spec.pl
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:1:55:W: cannot generate system identifier for public text "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V3.1//EN"
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:9:0:E: reference to entity "BOOK" for which no system identifier could be generated
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:1:0: entity was defined here
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:9:0:E: DTD did not contain element declaration for document type name
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:11:11:E: there is no attribute "LANG"
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:11:19:E: there is no attribute "ID"
nsgmls:../../doc/docbook-utils.sgml:11:34:E: element "BOOK" undefined
...
```

This goes on for several more lines.

Comment: This is likely related to [this other one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11651/688).

Comment: If you find a source for support for DocBoook on LFS, please add that info here. I have tried creating docBook too, and I still need some help. (I haven't had time to look at it lately). You might do better with this on StackOverflow as there are many questions on xml, xslt there. (tag this as xml too?). Good Luck!

Comment: I'd try unpacking Debian sources on this machine, and mimicking the rules file. You could also do a build run on a Debian machine and copy over the transcript. Also the build depends listed for Debian are (excluding debhelper) docbook-dsssl, jade, perl, sgmlspl, sp. Do you have those installed?

Answer (score 1):

This means that it didn't find the DocBook DTD of the required version.  Tracing the instructions you link to the [installation of the DocBook DTD](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/pst/sgml-dtd-3.html), they set up a catalog entry for DTD version 3.0, whereas they are installing version 3.1.  So those instructions are wrong.  You need a line like this instead:

```
PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V3.1//EN" "docbook.dtd"
```

By the way, these DocBook versions are really ancient (1997/1999), so if LFS still recommends installing them, I would tread cautiously around the instructions they give.